# Inequality between random variables and its implications

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $0 \leq X_1, X_2 \leq 1$ be two random variables I have an expression that looks like this:
$$\left| |t| - |X_1 -X_2|\right|$$ where $t$ is some constant. For any particular realisation of $X_1, X_2$ one can use triangle inequality of the $|.|$ and can write
$$\begin{align*}\left| |t| - |X_1 -X_2|\right| &= \left| |t- (X_1 -X_2) + (X_1 - X_2)| - |X_1 -X_2|\right| \\
&\leq \left| |t- (X_1 -X_2)| +  |X_1 - X_2| - |X_1 -X_2|\right| \\
&\leq \left |t- (X_1 -X_2)\right|
\end{align*}$$

Lets call $A=\left| |t| - |X_1 -X_2|\right|$ and $B=\left |t- (X_1 -X_2)\right|$ Since the above inequality holds for all realisations of $X_1, X_2$ one can say
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[A\right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[ B\right]. 
$$
But can we also make a probabilistic statement like the following. I intuitively see that this can be true. But if its true is there a way to prove it (by using Markov inequality or other concentration inequalities)?
$$
P(A > \epsilon) \leq P(B > \epsilon)
$$

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Do you mean to show that $P(A>\varepsilon) \le P(B > \varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, or just that there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $P(A>\varepsilon) \le P(B > \varepsilon)$?

Comment: would it matter? Typically for any $\epsilon$

Comment: Sorry, you're right, for this problem it wouldn't matter.  If we only knew that $\mathbb{E}[A] \le \mathbb{E}[B]$, though, it would matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A \le B$, we have $\{A > \varepsilon\} \subseteq \{B > \varepsilon\}$, so by monotonicity of probability $P(A > \varepsilon) \le P(B > \varepsilon)$.

Comment: For someone who wants to look deeper by what was meant by mononocity: https://statproofbook.github.io/P/prob-mon.html